Android Jetpack Compose not properly letting through all touch release events to a WebView
So I've been struggling for days finding out why my webview based app was not properly letting go of touch events, if I used multi touch and released both fingers at once it would only release 1 of the fingers leaving the webapp with sticky touch events.
I tried the following things:

Checked all sorts of things in my webapp if they could be blocking something. No dice.
Different webviews, old new, chrome, android webview. No dice.
Built a basic html test page which doesn't have anything else than a few touch events and logging for them. No Dice.
Built a clean Composable WebView project using (https://medium.com/@sahar.asadian90/webview-in-jetpack-compose-71f237873c2e). No dice.
Built a clean XML WebView project. FIXED!

Has anyone ran into this and found a way to prevent compose from screwing with the touch events in the webview? I have 1 app that's pretty easily rebuilt using the old ways but I also have one that's quite woven in with the Composable concepts and will be a lot harder to rebuild.
I used this html to test for touches logging them on the right side of the page where you'll see "{touchevent} {activeTouches} | {changedTouches}"
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
<style>
    html, body { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; overflow: hidden; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

    .finger {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #finger1 { border: 1px solid red; }
    #finger2 { border: 1px solid green; }
    #finger3 { border: 1px solid blue; }
    #finger4 { border: 1px solid orange; }
    #finger5 { border: 1px solid yellow; }

    #log {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: black;
        color: lightskyblue;
        font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    #count {
        position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 5px; font-weight: bold; color: red;
    }

    #useragent {
        position: absolute;
        left: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        max-width: 300px;
    }
</style>

<div id="useragent"></div>
<div id="finger1" class="finger"></div>
<div id="finger2" class="finger"></div>
<div id="finger3" class="finger"></div>
<div id="finger4" class="finger"></div>
<div id="finger5" class="finger"></div>
<div id="log" ondblclick="event.target.innerText = ''"></div>
<div id="count"></div>

<script>
    const fingers = [document.getElementById('finger1'),
                    document.getElementById('finger2'),
                    document.getElementById('finger3'),
                    document.getElementById('finger4'),
                    document.getElementById('finger5')];
    const count = document.getElementById('count');
    const log = document.getElementById('log');

    function clog(msg) {
        log.innerText = msg + "\r\n" + log.innerText;
    }

    document.getElementById('useragent').innerText = window.navigator.userAgent;
    function setFinger(el, touch) {
        el.style.transform = `translate(${touch.clientX-20}px, ${touch.clientY-20}px)`;
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
        clog(`touchstart\xa0 ${event.touches.length} | ${event.changedTouches?.length}`);
        count.innerText = event.touches.length;
        for (let i = 0, l = 5; i < l; i++) {
            const touch = event.touches.item(i);
            if (!touch) {
                fingers[i].style.display = 'translate(0, 0)';
                return;
            }

            setFinger(fingers[i], touch);
        }
    }, { passive: true });

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
        clog(`touchmove\xa0\xa0 ${event.touches?.length} | ${event.changedTouches?.length}`);
        count.innerText = event.touches.length;
        for (let i = 0, l = 5; i < l; i++) {
            const touch = event.touches.item(i);
            if (!touch) {
                fingers[i].style.display = 'translate(0, 0)';
                return;
            }

            setFinger(fingers[i], touch);
        }
    }, { passive: true });

    document.addEventListener('touchend', (event) => {
        clog(`touchend\xa0\xa0\xa0 ${event.touches?.length} | ${event.changedTouches?.length}`);
        count.innerText = event.touches?.length;
        for (let i = 0, l = 5; i < l; i++) {
            const touch = event.touches.item(i);
            if (!touch) {
                fingers[i].style.display = 'translate(0, 0)';
                return;
            }

            setFinger(fingers[i], touch);
        }
    }, { passive: true });

    document.addEventListener('touchcanel', (event) => {
        clog(`touchcancel ${event.touches?.length} | ${event.changedTouches?.length}`);
        count.innerText = event.touches?.length;
        for (let i = 0, l = 5; i < l; i++) {
            const touch = event.touches.item(i);
            if (!touch) {
                fingers[i].style.display = 'translate(0, 0)';
                return;
            }

            setFinger(fingers[i], touch);
        }
    }, { passive: true });
</script>

</body>
</html>

